# Need to create an event handler that can remove itself when the event occurs

Tags: c#, wpf, design-patterns, event-handling

I'm not really sure how to do this, as I've never had a need for this pattern just yet. I'm looking for the correct pattern on creating an event handler in a separate class that can remove itself when the object that contains the event executes.

Basically, I want to create an `EventHandler` that occurs on the WPF `Window.Close` event. And, during the execution of the handler it removes itself from the `Window.Close` event. I hope that's specific enough to go on.

Also, is there a specific name for this pattern?

Comment: Why does it have to remove itself from Window.Close? Is the event handler injected in the form or exists locally? If a local function listens to the event then it is unhooked automatically when the form  instance goes out of scope.

Comment: The event is generated in a separate class, not within the Window itself.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try to do something like next:

```
 RoutedEventHandler handlerLoad = null;
 handlerLoad = delegate
        {
            //Do something
            Window.Close -= handlerLoad;
        };

Window.Close += handlerLoad;
```

Comment: This looks sound, but ReSharper complains about a "Access to mofified closure". I'm guessing I can ignore that since I'm purposely doing just that... Also, I guess it helps to declare the local variable to null first so it can be reused inside of the delegate.

Comment: I think this solution relies on the system executing event handlers in the same order they are registered. This is an implementation detail, not guaranteed by Microsoft, therefore I won't rely on it.

Answer (score 2):

would something like the following work?

```
public void EventHandlerSubscription_Invoked(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
    _objectContainingEvent.MyEventHandler -= EventHandlerSubscription;
}
```

Sorry if this isn't sensible, I'm typing off the top of my head.

Answer (score 1):

Please tell more about the 'what' of your project : what do you intend to do.
Maybe you would be interested in manual reset event, that triggers only
once unless you reset them :
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.manualresetevent.aspx